# Multiple parameters for the __contains__ function

Tags: python, contains

Is it possible to pass the "__ contains __" function in a list more than one parameter? I'd like to check if *at least* one of the items i have in a list exist in a different list.

For example:
[0,1,4,8,87,6,4,7,5,'a','f','er','fa','vz']

I'd like to check if the one of the items (8,5,'f') are on that list.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use sets:

```
list1 = [0,1,4,8,87,6,4,7,5,'a','f','er','fa','vz']
tuple1 = (8,5,'f')

def my_contains(first, second):
    return bool(set(first).intersection(second))

my_contains(list1, tuple1) # True
my_contains(list1, [1]) # True
my_contains(list1, (125,178,999)) # False
```

Comment: +1, nice use of set.  _intersection()_ can take the second iterable directly.  You can produce a True/False just by calling bool(someset).  `return bool(set(first).intersection(second))`

Comment: One key point to note is that set-based approaches only work if all values involved are hashable. If that cannot be guaranteed then it is necessary to adopt an iterative solution (likely using the `any` builtin).

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK, `__contains__` takes only one argument and it can't be changed.

However you can do following to get the desired result :

```
>>> a = [0,1,4,8,87,6,4,7,5,'a','f','er','fa','vz']
>>> any(map(lambda x: x in a, (8,5,'f')))
True
```

or

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> from operator import contains
>>> f = partial(contains, a)
>>> any(map(f, (2,3)))
False
```

Comment: +1 for the use of any, also nice to demonstrate partial.  It is more pythonic to use a generator instead of map+lambda.

Comment: As kevpie noted, that first suggestion would be significantly cleaner as `any(x in a for x in (8,5,'f'))`. Whenever a lambda is being passed as the first argument to `map` it is a strong hint that a comprehension or generator expression should be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use the builtin **[set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set)** type.

```
>>> l =  [0,1,4,8,87,6,4,7,5,'a','f','er','fa','vz']
>>> s = (8,5,'f')
>>> bool(set(s) & set(l))
True
```

Set methods will take iterables as arguments too, avoiding the creation of the set.

**Most Concise:**

2.6 provides **set.isdisjoint(other)** which likely is optimized to return as soon as a common element is found.

```
>>> not set(l).isdisjoint(s)
True
```

**If you want to loop:**

```
>>> any((val in s) for val in l)
True
```